# "Impossible" NPE in a multi-threaded situation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-8, rx-java2

I have some inherently asynchronous code in an Android app. I'm using RxJava2. The class `Thing` is not under my control (but `ThingFactory` is). In one method (`createThing()`), a new `Thing` is instantiated. `Thing`'s constructor does some work and, when it is complete, notifies us via a callback `onThingInitialized()`. At the point that callback is called, we should be guaranteed that `thing` exists. In the callback, I schedule work to happen on a separate thread (in this case, using RxJava2, but I don't think it should matter). There is nowhere in this code that I call anything like `thing = null`. So, once it's set, it's set forever.

I threw a `volatile` onto it because the instance *does* get updated, but never nulled. If I'm mis-using it, please feel free to berate me.

```
public class UsesAThing implements ThingCallbacks {

    private volatile Thing thing; // I feel like I don't understand 'volatile'

    // I call this method
    public void createThing() {
        thing = thingFactory.newThing(param1, param2);
    }

    // Thing's constructor does some work and notifies us when it's done
    @Override
    public void onThingInitialized() {
        // Called on main thread, but I want to do some IO work, so:
        Schedulers.io().scheduleDirect(() -> {
            thing.doStuff(); // NPE!
        });
    }
}
```

**How is an NPE possible there?**

**EDIT:**

`Thing`'s constructor does its work asynchronously. As I said, this is in an Android environment, so the work it's actually doing is binding to a `Service`. When the `Service` is bound, its `ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected()` callback is hit, which itself actually fires up an `AsyncTask` which, in its `onPostExecute()` callback, calls the `onThingInitialized()` callback.

**EDIT 2:**

I should also note that this NPE doesn't happen all the time. I've run through this code hundreds of time, and I've only seen it occur once.

**EDIT 3: Sample calling code**

I didn't provide sample code because it's about as simple as one might imagine, but here's what it looks like:

```
Flowable.just(1)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(i -> createThing());
```

Comment: "Thing's constructor does some work and, when it is complete, notifies us via a callback onThingInitialized()."  Is the callback synchronous or asynchronous?  If it's synchronous, `newThing` hasn't returned and thus `thing` hasn't been assigned when `onThingInitialized` is called.  It may or may not be assigned before `thing` is dereferenced by the worker thread.

Comment: I've updated my question to address this.

Comment: In what thread do you call `createThing()`?

Comment: It's created as the result of a successful REST call on `RxCachedThreadScheduler-1`. The NPE happened on `RxCachedThreadScheduler-2`. Both use `Schedulers.io()` from RxJava2.

Comment: You really need to give us some code here that calls all this stuff.  Otherwise we're guessing.  But in general, if you have an object initialized on another thread and a callback when its ready, I'd be passing it in via the callback rather than keeping a reference to it laying around.

Comment: It's library code, so I don't have access to that object via the callback. I added some sample calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your comment, `createThing()` is called in a worker thread.  It's unlikely but possible that the thread scheduler will halt this worker thread after the `Thing` constructor initiates the sequence of events that leads to the callback, but *before* `newThing()` returns and `thing` is assigned.  If the whole callback sequence runs before the thread calling `createThing()` runs again, you will see this NPE.

To test this theory, first create a test that runs repeatedly to reproduce the issue.  Then change it so `createThing()` is called in the main thread and see if the problem goes away.  That would be a workaround, not a fix.  But a real fix would involve not doing work in `Thing`'s constructor, which you stated is out of your control.

Comment: I'm inclined to think you're right. I'll report back if/when I get some tests to verify. I may also just file a PR with the library to take the initialization out of the constructor.

Comment: If `onThingInitialized` receives the thing that was initialized, you could use that reference to call `doStuff`.

Comment: Given that this work is done in a constructor, it's not clear how to accomplish that in a non-trivial way. However, I did just file a trivial (though breaking) PR with the library on Github to pull the initialization code out of the constructor, which would solve this problem. https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/pull/252